# WordPress install in subfolder

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to test a new wordpress site on a clients server. Annoyingly he doesn't have the ability to add subdomains. So, I'm trying to install WP into a subfolder on the server and run it from there.

Essentially instead of the wp site being at `siteurl.com`, I want it at `siteurl.com/wp` without affecting any of the files on the rest of the server.

I've uploaded all of the files to the sub-folder, added the new DB and changed the `siteurl` and the `home` rows in the `wp_options` table. However, when I load the page, I get nothing. Chrome gives me the message "Server Error".

If I remove all the data from the DB, I get shown to WP install page. But I'm a little worried that if I fill this out, it's going to make the homepage of the site siteurl.com rather than siteurl.com/wp

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change the url in database. Just install your wordpress for siteurl.com. and create a folder named `wp`. install another wordpress in this folder. you will get access for both url, you have to create different database for both of the urls

Comment: There is no wordpress for siteurl.com. The original site is built on a custom framework and is still running live making the client money so cannot be messed with. Hence my carefulness about installing a WP site in a subfolder.